# Create a sub-site using a JavaScript Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I have been trying to create a button which will add a new sub-site to an existing site. This is the JavaScript code I have currently. I also have a button which calls the `createNewSite()` method.

```
//Global Variables
var web;
var clientContext;

function createNewSite(){
    //get the current site that the javascript is being run on
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    //load the web object data
    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed, fail);
}

//Async Call succeeded
function succeed(){
    console.log("First ExecuteQuery Succeeded");
    //Create an object containing the necessary creation information
    var newWeb = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
    newWeb.set_description('New Description');
    newWeb.set_title('New Title');
    newWeb.set_url("sites/Test/JSOMTest/NewSite");

    //add the new web based on creation information
    var newPage = web.get_webs().add(newWeb);
    web.update();

    //Try to save changes
    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(finished, fail); //---this call fails---//
}

//Async call to SharePoint failed
function fail( sender, args ) {
    alert("Much Fail");
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
}

//Completed successfully 
function finished(){
    alert("Much Success");
}
```

This code runs until the second execute query at which point it fails, giving the message "Error: Value cannot be null."

I have tried various methods suggested by other questions on this topic, all which give me the same problem. Which makes me think that I am doing something more fundamental wrong.

When testing to try to identify the problem adding the line `console.log(web.get_title());` (shown in asterisks in the code below) creates an error, saying:

> "Uncaught Error: The property or field 'Title' has not been
>   initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been
>   executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

It then terminates execution.

```
//Global Variables
var web;
var clientContext;

function createNewSite(){
    //get the current site that the javascript is being run on
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    //load the web object data
    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeed, fail);
}

//Async Call succeeded
function succeed(){
    console.log("First ExecuteQuery Succeeded");
    ***console.log(web.get_title());***
    //Create an object containing the necessary creation information
    var newWeb = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
    newWeb.set_description('New Description');
    newWeb.set_title('New Title');
    newWeb.set_url("sites/Test/JSOMTest/NewSite");

    //add the new web based on creation information
    var newPage = web.get_webs().add(newWeb);
    web.update();

    //Try to save changes
    clientContext.load(web);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(finished, fail);
}

//Async call to SharePoint failed
function fail( sender, args ) {
    alert("Much Fail");
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
}

//Completed successfully 
function finished(){
    alert("Much Success");
}
```

*asterisks are to show the additional line and are not included in the executable code

If anyone knows why this is not working, what I am doing wrong and/or how to actually do this your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much code :)

Have Modified, Simplified and Tested the below working  code:

```
function createNewSite() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();

    var newWeb = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
    newWeb.set_title('New Title');
    newWeb.set_description('New Description');  
    newWeb.set_url('NewSite');

    web.get_webs().add(newWeb);
    web.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(data){
        console.log("success");
    },function(sender, args){
        console.log("failure" + args.get_message());
    });
}
```

Modified from here - [Create site with jsom in sp hosted app](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e52346e0-0592-451d-881d-2d49d237ffd5/create-site-with-jsom?forum=appsforsharepoint)